# Why wont mirroring of the Brush work properly?

Tags: texture-painting

I want to do the texturing but I countered a problem I couldn't solve.

I thought the x-axis is red and the y-axis green.

[image: default x-axis red and y-axis green]

But when I turn the mirror in texture paint on x-axis it mirrors the paint around the y-axis and with y-axis enabled the other way round.

On top with y-axis enabled it is strangely shifted.

I already tried setting the origin of the model to volume and moved the object to the center with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> , but it didn't change. Also I tried to texture paint a cube in a new file to see if it's working there and it does properly. Next I tried to copy the fly to a new file and texture paint it over there but I encountered the same problem.

[image: x-axis mirror enabled]

[image: y-axis mirror enbabled]

Answer (score 1):

You may need to go in edit mode and select a single loop of vertex to snap the cursor to that will allow you to place the origin center so that your object will paint correctly. A common problem for mesh that has been moved in edit mode away from the origin is this effect, that the center will be offset incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I switched to edit mode and selected a loop of vertexes, then I pressed "Shift+S" and selected "Cursor to Selected". Then I set the origin ("F3 -> set origin") and selected "Origin to 3D Cursor". Was that right? It didn't fix the problem with the texture paint mirroring for me :/

Comment: If you then append your mesh to another file, does it still fail there?

Comment: yeah I already tried that since texture painting mirroring worked fine with the default cube of a new file. But when I copy paste the mesh of my fly over to a new file I still encounter the same problem with the mirroring there. It seems my mesh is somehow the cause. Maybe I should just paint both sites of the mesh manually then, the mirror just would have made it easier.

Comment: It’s not the mirror that is wrong but this fly object is built off center and is causing the system to fail you. If you have to, make copy and delete half so you can use a mirror modifier to examine what is going on with the geo. Original should be saved and adjusted once you can figure out how to properly reset the origin.